# accsess of windows 8 without PIN option

Tags: windows, windows-8

I woke up this morning and found that i couldnt access my laptop.I had a PIN option and also the password.But now the PIN option is not there and only asking last used password fot the PC.When i gave that it did not accept.Even the pin option menu is not coming.I cant even connect to internet.So what to do now.Please help.I do not want to lose my files in C drive.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to deal with a similar problem with a user's personal computer, but that was a while back. It looks like there are some graphical methods now. The method I used involved replacing the file accessed when clicking the "Accessibility" button on the logon screen with cmd.exe, so you could then modify user settings without logging in (as outlined here: http://www.top-password.com/knowledge/reset-forgotten-windows-8-password.html).

If you'd prefer not to deal with the commandline, here is a link to a video showing another method: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HoYv1H6-E98. It involves downloading Hiren's Boot CD (I've used it before, it's a disc image you can download that is a compilation of a bunch of bootable utilities that are useful for diagnosing and fixing various problems), using it to boot into a Windows XP environment, and running a tool that will let you edit (or remove) the password.